# Angular component library - image references in templates

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack

I have an npm package that has a number of angular components. In their templates, they reference images. If I copy the images to my application's `images` directory, the references resolve, but this feels stupid.

Is there a way to have webpack handle image writing so that when App B includes components from App A, the images work in the build and there's no manual copy step involved?

Comment: can you add folder structure and webpack config?

Comment: have you tried with https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader ?

Comment: @stefan, adding to what @Jaganathan said can you please share some code of what already has been done. Also do mention whether you are trying bundling in the `dev` env or `prod`.

Comment: Answered this same question in my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111478/angular-cli-how-to-reference-image-paths-in-reusable-components/45151203#45151203

Comment: Answered this question in my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111478/angular-cli-how-to-reference-image-paths-in-reusable-components/45151203#45151203

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If images are not properly required in this npm package then webpack won't be able to process them. You may try something like [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) or write own copy script to avoid manual copying

Comment: Probably the best answer. Just export the images in the library via package.json, and copy them to your images directory via gulp. There doesn't seem to be a better way to do this via webpack.

Comment: Answered this question in my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111478/angular-cli-how-to-reference-image-paths-in-reusable-components/45151203#45151203

Comment: @ruhler your question is about angular 2 and higher while this question is about AngularJS. These are different angulars